# How to apply Scroll items in Canvas in windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, canvas, windows-phone-8

How can i make Scroll in the Items resides in the Canvas.There is listbox inside the canvas which contains DataTemplate with the control image and textblock and  I am using the following code but it was not worked.

```
   <ScrollViewer x:Name="scvImages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Grid.Row="1"   Visibility="Visible" Background="Black" Opacity="0.7"  Grid.RowSpan="2">

                <ListBox x:Name="lstcountry" Margin="0,50,0,0">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid x:Name="content" Height="70" Width="480">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=img}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="70" Width="150"></Image>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="countryname" Text="{Binding Path=short_name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Padding="0,15,0,0" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="32" FontFamily="The Times of Roman"></TextBlock>
                                <Border x:Name="brd1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,2,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ></Border>

                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>

            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to enable scrolling in scrollviewer change height Auto to some definite height

```
            <ListBox x:Name="lstcountry" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="300">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid x:Name="content" Height="70" Width="480">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=img}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="70" Width="150"></Image>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="countryname" Text="{Binding Path=short_name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Padding="0,15,0,0" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="32" FontFamily="The Times of Roman"></TextBlock>
                            <Border x:Name="brd1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,2,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ></Border>

                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>

        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But i suggest you to remove scrollviewer and canvas control from your layout. because both are usefulness. If i guess right you need scrolling in your ListBox control and The Listbox control has it's own scroll implementation. You should remove height property from listbox if you define height of grid's 1st row like

```
<RowDefination Height="*"/>
or
<RowDefination Height="400"/>
```

```
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid x:Name="content" Height="70" Width="480">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=img}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="70" Width="150"></Image>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="countryname" Text="{Binding Path=short_name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Padding="0,15,0,0" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="32" FontFamily="The Times of Roman"></TextBlock>
                            <Border x:Name="brd1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,2,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ></Border>

                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Auto` for `ScrollViewer`. `Auto` stretches the `ScrollViewer` same size as canvas. You need to set fixed height so content can be scrolled within it.

Answer (score 0):

The list box control has it's own scroll implementation. Unless you are going to have other elements along side the list box, I would remove the scroll viewer and canvas elements.